# Java: How to replace everything except of [0-9] and "sin","cos","tan","ctg", "(" , ")" in String

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I need to replace all characters in a string except these ones : [0-9] and "sin", "cos", "tan", "ctg", "(" , ")"

I think I need to use `String.replaceAll("some regex","")` but can't figure right regex.

For example, if I have this String: `123321323n3k332313jbj323sin232323jkjctg2323`.
I need to get this one after replacing : `1233213233332313323sin232323ctg2323`

Need to replace bad characters with empty characters ""

solution: `String.replaceAll("(c(?:os|tg)|sin|tan)|[^0-9\\(\\)]","$1");` thanks to Krayo

Comment: Replace with what ? Unclear.

Comment: for sure, sorry forgot that.

Comment: It's much clear now!

Comment: What if you needed to keep just numbers, can you figure such regex?

Comment: Yes, it will be myString.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");

Comment: You are right you do need regex . here is a cheat sheet for regular expressions http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/ . Its easy to learn .Try to come up with one for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
(c(?:os|tg)|sin|tan)|[^0-9)(]
```

with this replacement string:

```
$1
```

The content between parentheses is tested first and captured. `$1` is the reference to this capture. If the contents of those parentheses is not matched, then nothing is captured and the `$1` reference resolved to the empty string.

`(?:...)` delimits only a non capturing group, useful for the two possibilities `os` and `tg` after a `c`.

To translate in plain English what this regex does: replace anything that isn't digits or parentheses with

- itself if it is one of "cos", "sin", "tan" or "ctg"
- nothing otherwise.

Comment: You forgot about the parentheses characters '(' and ')' that the OP wants to keep. So the resulting regex would be `(c(?:os|tg)|sin|tan)|[^0-9\(\)]`

Comment: @madshogo: indeed <°)))))))))))))))))>

Comment: and Hippolyte uuugh... and i made a mistake myself. We don't want to be replacing the parentheses now do we. Shouldn't you escape the `(` and `)` characters though?

Comment: @madshogo: No you was right, parenthesis need to be preserved. you don't need to escape parenthesis (and other special characters) inside a character class.

Comment: @madshogo: except the hyphen `-` if it is not at the begining or at the end (since it used to define a character range), the caret `^` if it is at the begining (since it's used to negate the class), and the closing square bracket `]` if it is not at the begining or after a caret at the begining.

Comment: @madshogo: Note that in some flavour that use pattern delimiters, the delimiter need to be escaped too, but it's not the case in Java.

Comment: @madshogo: to be fully rigourus, If you write two consecutives ampersands `&&` you can escape one of them to not be ambigous with the class intersection syntax: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html

Comment: If I try this regex:`"1234sin123si32".replaceAll("(c(?:os|tg)|sin|tan)|[^0-9\\(\\)]","\\1");` I get this result: `"123411231132"` but not `"1234sin12332"` as it should be, what should I fix?

Comment: @AndreyKle Try this: `replaceAll("(c(?:os|tg)|sin|tan)|[^0-9\(\)]","$1");`

Comment: @AndreyKle: sorry, I have forgotten that the backreference in a replacement string is with a dollar in Java.

Comment: @Krayo: no need to escape special characters in a character class, read the previous comments. Thanks anyway for this correction.

Comment: Yeah, that was a copying mistake :)